# FileHandler specified in 'WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties' becomes polluted by extra records

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

According to Tomcat [reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) I have decided to setup logging per application. I have specified the following handler in file 'WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties' in application dir:

```
handlers = 5orderbook.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

5orderbook.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
5orderbook.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5orderbook.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = orderbook.
```

The logging file is created. But I even didn't setup any particular logger (or 'facility' according to the reference) while got the following extra records:

```
янв 29, 2016 9:18:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [my.app.config.SecurityInitializer@34dff4af]
янв 29, 2016 9:18:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
янв 29, 2016 9:18:35 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
<...>
```

When I assigned the handler to particular package nothing changes:

```
my.level = FINE
my.handlers = 5orderbook.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

What I do wrong? How to prevent the polluting of log file by non related records?

Comment: I'm not sure about if using of 'juli.FileHandler' in applications is a kind of a 'criminal'. So I tried similar config with jul.FileHandler. The result is the same:  `handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler`  

`java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE`
`java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`
`java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = "%t/orderbook%u.log"`

`my.level = INFO`
`my.handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler`

Comment: So you set up per-application logging, and you want to know why your application is logging to your application's log? (!!?)

Comment: The 'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext' and especially 
'org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader' are not my app's classes, so I don't want them polluting my app's log.That's why I specified: my.handlers=... , to narrow the allowed loggers to certain package. I expect that only loggers from 'my.*' packages are able to write to customized FileHandler.

Comment: `org.springframework.whatever` is most certainly a part of your application -- it's obviously not a part of Tomcat. If you don't want to see those components logging to your logger, then configure the logger to *not* log anything from those classes. Also, the `ApplicationContext` logging is what happens when the application calls `ServletContext.log()`, which obviously should be a part of the application's log file.

Comment: I suppose, I must not explicitly "configure to not log", because in normal circumstances  if the handler is not assigned to any 'log category' (or namespace) then it must not write any messages from that category.  
Meanwhile, in other sample the logger _did_ write Spring's and Tomcat's log messages even when I subclassed it from j.u.l.FileHandler. It just ignored the property: 'my.handlers = my.logging.MyHandler' (where 'my' is the package name). If it _should_ ignore this property, then, what this property made for?

Comment: You set both the *default* handler as well as *your code's* handler to the same handler, which you sent to a file. So it's logging everything to that file. If you want your stuff in one file and everything else somewhere else, youll need to define two handlers and set one as the default (includes Spring, other stuff, etc.) and the other only for your own code. I recommend reading more about how logging works with `java.util.logging` and Tomcat's customization of it: JULI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like 'feature' of built-in Spring dependency called Jakarta Commons Logging. After excluding the commons-logging dependency and replacing it with jcl-over-slf4f the Spring's records have disappeared from the application's log file. Here is my pom.xml elements:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>
```